# Reporting Services chart text is blurry when rendered in ReportViewer control on web page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

**Issue**

We are rendering a bar chart on a web page using a Reporting Services report and the ReportViewer control. Sometimes the text on the chart is sharp:

[image: Chart with text that is sharp]

But most of the time, the text on the chart is blurry:

[image: Chart with text that is blurry]

What is going on?

**Steps Taken to Resolve and Other Information**

- Extensive search of web and SO
- Tried different browsers, users and machines; couldn't determine rhyme or reason to blurriness
- Tried several settings of SSRS report properties `DynamicHeight` and `DynamicWidth`
- In Firefox, when right-clicking on the chart image and choosing **View image**, the displayed image is *always* sharp
- The issue seems more prominent on charts with a border; removed border on chart, but issue remains

**Affects Browsers**

- Firefox 15.0
- Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m
- IE 9 but only while in Browser Mode=IE9, Document Mode=IE9 Standards

**Environment**

- Visual Studio 2010 Pro
- .NET 4.0
- IIS 7.0
- Reporting Services 2008
- ReportViewer control version 10

Answer (score 14):

**Cause**

The ReportViewer control renders charts as a PNG image. The ReportViewer adds `width`, `height`, and `min-width` properties to the CSS for the image. These CSS properties cause the image to undergo scaling to a slightly *smaller* size in the browser. The image scaling causes the observed blurriness.

**Resolution**

The issue is resolved in our environment by using additional CSS to override several CSS properties rendered by the ReportViewer. The Reporting Services chart is given a special tag in BIDS so a CSS selector can find the affected image.

Step 1. Give the chart a unique value for its `ToolTip` property:

[image: Unique value for ToolTip property in BIDS]

(The unique value in this example is *MyOfficeChart*.)

When the chart is rendered as an `<img>`, the `<img>` tag's `alt` and `title` attributes are set to this value.

Step 2. Create CSS to select the `<img>` by the unique value of the `title` attribute, and override the issue-causing CSS:

```
img[title$='MyOfficeChart']
{
    height:auto !important;
    width:auto !important;
    min-width:0 !important;
}
```

These steps resolve the issue for all browsers and users, and whether the chart has a border or not.

Comment: Great fix.  I did this but changed the selector to:  
    img[title$='Chart']  
So I don't need to create multiple rules

Comment: I had a problem with the chart having a width of zero using V12, and this worked to fix the chart width also.

Comment: Are you adding the CSS within the SSRS RDL file?

Comment: @gruff, no. The ReportViewer control is embedded in a custom ASP.NET application, so we added the CSS to the application's CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

An easy was to resolve this is by putting a rectangle directly into your tablix cell, and then put the chart inside of that rectangle.  (Instead of having the chart directly in the tablix cell.)

Not 100% sure why it works... but it does.

Comment: Although my chart isn't in a tablix cell, I wanted to try this method anyway. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me: the chart was still blurry.

Answer (score -1):

This is not proper solution but could help. The steps are as follows:

1. Open report rdl in report builder
2. select the chart's text, that gets blurred
3. Type 'C' in Font Style (on top menu) and press enter
4. Font style change but unknown
5. Try to run and see the difference